# Split string by length in java as my requirement

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a String with length `721` like following :

```
String stmnt="27/08/2013 Cr 00000000000288.70 AMOUNT DEPOSITED FOR TELEPHONE EXPENSES  22/08/2013 Dr 00000000085000.00 PMT TO abcde BOHARA                     20/08/2013 Cr 00000000015844.38 BEING REFUND AMOUNT DEPOSITED OF RMDC IP20/08/2013 Cr 00000000047419.09 BEING REFUND AMOUNT DEPOSITED OF SKBBL I15/08/2013 Dr 00000000002900.00 PMT TO lkjhgd 09876543                  12/08/2013 Dr 00000000001723.00 PMT TO SELF                             12/08/2013 Cr 00000000025563.00 liuytrew /SALARY / 070 / 748392 lkoiuytr08/08/2013 Dr 00000000002000.00 PMT TO SELF                             07/08/2013 Dr 00000000000500.00 PMT TO 123456 nmnbvsgd                  29/07/2013 Cr 00000000002000.00 DE PO BY SELF                           ";
```

One string should be length of 72. In string `stmnt` there should be 10 statements it means total length **720**. The first statement of string `stmnt` should be following:

```
string should be ="27/08/2013 Cr 00000000000288.70 AMOUNT DEPOSITED FOR TELEPHONE EXPENSES ";
```

But the problem is there is **padding one more space**  like following:

```
irritated string="27/08/2013 Cr 00000000000288.70 AMOUNT DEPOSITED FOR TELEPHONE EXPENSES  ";
```

on first string so it is the problem that is irritating to me.

The **definition** of one string as follows:

```
 1. first 10 digits are : date with length 10 and startIndex 0
 2. next 4 digits are transaction type (CR/DR) `including spaces
    also`  and startIndex 10
 3. next 18 digits are Account Balance including one space on right
    side and startIndex 14
 4. and rest 40 digits are particular  startIndex 32
```

My Question is I need to split length of 72 string as defining on **definition section.**

**NOTE:** I can do individually using `String.subString()` but need to solution for all string. Because I need to parse 721 length of string at a time.

**Update:** Need `regex` code that will make 72 length for all string. Condition should be as I described on **definition** section

Comment: Well you know the index's of each part of the String, why not just use some substrings of the main String in your program?

Comment: Please do not down vote. Comment I will try to explain

Comment: @Tdorno Sir I tried many times. It is not parsing. This is the ministatement of bank account. Having problem on ISO8583 message format to parse

Comment: google "java.lang.String substring"

Comment: @KalathokiL. So your problem is regarding the irritated string?

Comment: @KalathokiL. Show us how you attempted to implement the substring approach, because it should work quite nicely. If not it may just be a better approach to set up your own `Scanner` to scan element from the `String` individually. **Also on the irritated String why not just call `trim()` to remove the last padded space.**

Comment: @itsmeisuru No, The main problem is only by one more space on right side of my first 73 length string. If first string's length was 72 I could.

Comment: @Tdorno The code is depending more than five classes. But I am trying to update if possible.

Comment: So, you are saying that the "contract" you have with the API provider is that you should get 1 string with 10 "statements", each being 72 characters long, but the first one appears to be 73 characters long instead?  I think you need to contact the API provider and tell them their stuff is broken.  That aside, you might want to look at using regex instead to parse the string, using the date as a delimiter/start-of-record?

Comment: So are you saying that the first string has length 73, but the others have 72?

Comment: @CodeChimp Depending on the relationship to the data provider, the answer may be "we don't care."  Sometimes you have to work around broken data.

Comment: @CharlesForsythe You are correct, but if that is the case, then you need to code around it.  Determine if the string is ALWAYS 73 characters vs. sometimes, then figure a solution to correct it.  Is it always just the first one, or could it be, say, the 1st one time and 4th the next?  You should be able to tell if one more more are borked based on the total length of the string not being a multiple of 72.  I personally would switch to a Regex, using the start of a date-looking string as the start of a new record.

Comment: @Ingo I code on length `72` for all but server is sending 73 length for first string. But others all are 72 length

Comment: @CodeChimp Yes only first string length is 73 but all are 72.

Comment: I think @CharlesForsythe has your answer below.  The regex he provided might need some tweaking, but should provide a means to separate the string based on a starting "date" looking thing followed by the appropriate number of characters that make a "record".

Answer (score 4):

I would use a regular expression like the code below.  I haven't tested this, so you'll need to tweak it.  The benefit of using the regex is that is will not "mind" if there are extra spaces between the fixed-length records.

```
p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4} (Cr|Dr) \\d{14}\\.\\d{2} .{50})");
m = p.matcher(bigRecord);

while(m.find()) {
    String record = m.group();
}
```

Edited per Ingo's comment.  The suggested Regex is just a rough estimate of what would actually be needed for this data set, so further refinements are almost certainly required.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.  I always thing Regex is the way to go when parsing string data like this.

Comment: Need regex for full 721 length string. Because I need to parse at a time

Comment: I think what I posted is (mostly) what you need.  It splits the string into 72-character records, even if the first one has an extra space (73 characters).